# execution stops with no errors thrown during jdbc connection

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, database-connection

Just got done setting everything up and ran my code. but java doesn't throw any errors so I don't know what is wrong. Here is my setup
win7 - sql server 2008 express r2 - eclipse-everything on one computer(localhost). Here is code:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" +
        "databaseName=MyDatabase;user=sa;password=test;";
    System.out.println("AAA");

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);

    System.out.println("BBB");

    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Friends");
```

so up to printing AAA there are no errors thrown. Then nothing happens. No errors and BBB never prints. Something wrong with Connection conn declaration but what? No error messages at all so What should I look at now? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the code around a try/catch, as shown below:

```
try {
  //your code here
} catch(SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Within the 'catch' you should see some detail on what is going on.

A good tutorial on JDBC is located at http://www.jdbc-tutorial.com

Good luck!

Comment: i actually have that already. but didn't post it. sorry. what next?

Comment: Post the stack trace of any exception you're getting.

Comment: Yep, post the stack trace so we can get a better idea of what's going on for ya.

Comment: No exceptions were thrown when i ran code. The console just prints AAA

Answer (score 1):

Try check value of `connectionUrl` is right or not.  Your waiting time until timeout of login to database when you call `DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl)`
 is `DriverManager.getLoginTimeout()`. Try check that value.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your sql server isn't running, and windows is timing out waiting for it to appear.

Confirm that the sql server is running, and confirm you can `ping localhost`.

Comment: Hello, I checked my Services SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) and it is Started. Also under my sql network configuration I have the following: Protocols for SQLEXPRESS->TCP/IP Enabled. When I right click->properties->then go to Ip addresses tab, I have all the IPs Active and Enabled set to Yes. However the IP addresses for all of them is some weird long hex number fe80::a0aa:58f5:b2ed:fb79%21. Could that be the problem? Also I have windows firewall turned off.

Answer (score 0):

After spending more than 8+ hrs on this problem, it all came down to stupid MS jdbc driver! I CAN'T BELIEVE THEIR OWN DRIVERS DON'T WORK WITH THEIR SOFTWARE!!! OMG. So after tons of searching it came down to using jtds jdbc driver and it works! sigh. Stay away from MS jdbc driver! I hope this can help others save some time.

Comment: LOL, sorry to hear that, but at least you found the problem!  MS JDBC drivers do not work with their own database, huh?  Why am I not surprised...